# How to sort two-line blocks in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a file with the following content:

```
/** doxygen comment for enum member1 */
COMMON_PREFIX_name1 = 1,
/** doxygen comment for enum member2 */
COMMON_PREFIX_name2 = 2,
/** doxygen comment for enum member3 */
COMMON_PREFIX_name3 = 3,
/** doxygen comment for enum member4 */
COMMON_PREFIX_name4 = 4,
...
```

Is is possible to sort the definitions by the `name1`, `name2`, etc. suffixes in the member names, and keep each comment above the corresponding definition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose the following sequence of actions.

1. Join the paired lines:

   ```
   :g/^\s*COMMON_PREFIX_/-j!
   ```
2. Sort the joined lines by the variable names’ suffixes:

   ```
   :sort#\*/\s*COMMON_PREFIX_#
   ```
3. Split the sorted lines back:

   ```
   :g#\*/\zs\ze\s*COMMON_PREFIX_#s//\r/
   ```

You can run all three commands at once:

```
:exe'g/^\s*COMMON_PREFIX_/-j!' | sort#\*/\s*COMMON_PREFIX_# | g#\*/\zs\ze\s*COMMON_PREFIX_#s//\r/
```

Comment: Could you please add some bits of explanation? I'm not sure what the -j! part is doing.

Comment: @johnny:  Sure.  The ending part (after the second slash) of a `:global` command is another Ex command to execute on the lines that match given pattern.  `-j!` runs the `:join` command with `!` modifier on the `-` range of lines.  `-`, in its turn, is the shortest form of a one-line range `.-1` referring to the line above the current one.

Comment: Thanks, I've always just used j, without - or !. I never knew I could join with the previous row. I'm sorry but I still don't understand the effect of '!'.

Comment: @johnny:  With `!` modifier the `:join` command does not insert or delete any spaces between joined lines.  The difference between `:j` and `:j!` Ex commands is the same as between `J` and `gJ` Normal mode ones.

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time to explain. I tried vim help but only found other meanings.